# How can i fix this try catch issue

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, try-catch

I'm new to the developer world and I'm trying to use a try catch in a react functional component in this way:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import { Row, Col, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import Input from "../Input/Input";

import AuthenticationServices from "../../services/AuthenticationServices";

const SignIn = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    repeatPassword,
    error,
  } = userData;


  const onChange = (e) => {
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    try {
      if (password === repeatPassword) {
        AuthenticationServices.register({
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          password: password,
        });
      } else {
        setUserData({
          ...userData,
          error: "Passwords don't match",
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setUserData({
        ...userData,
        error: err.response.data.error,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container
      fluid
      className="mx-auto p-5"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#ddd" }}
    >
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              onSubmit(e);
            }}
          >
            <Input
              label="Your name"
              placeholder="Insert your name"
              type="string"
              value={firstName}
              name="firstName"
              idNumber="0"
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              required={true}
              maxLength="5"
            ></Input>
...
```

The router manages post request on the register page by running AuthenticationController.register

the AuthenticationController.register method contains:

```
    try {
      const user = await User.create(req.body); // Creates a new user using the user model
      const userJSON = user.toJSON(); // Converts the user to JSON
      res.send({
        user: userJSON,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: `ERROR: Email already in use.`,
      });
    }
  },
```

At the moment i can display in a div "Passwords don't match" by setting `userData.error:"Passwords don't match"` .
The database accepts unique emails and I'm trying to use the try catch to catch the error in case of a repeated email but from what I see in my component it doesn't catch the error at all.
I tested it with postmain and in case of a repeated email i recive "ERROR: Email already in use." as expected

Comment: `try/catch` is for code that *throws* an error. Does your `AuthenticationServices.register` throw an error if emails aren't unique, or is it simply a valid response with some error status information? I think you probably want to `await` the response and check the status and set/update any state then.

Comment: `register(credentials) {
    return Api().post("register", credentials);
  }`

This is my AuthenticationService.

Comment: Hi, can you do a couple things? (1) include the response object from postman in your question, and (2) keep following the code to see what is returned/thrown, i.e. `register` returns `Api().post(..)`, what does `.post` return, etc...

Comment: I solved the problem. i wasn't using async await in the `onSubmit` function.

I posted the solved problem.

Comment: @DrewReese you got it in the first message but i didn't understand your answer because i was lacking of knowledge regarding the async await system, however thank you very much for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of a colleague.

Unluckly i didn't know how async await works so i took a while.

I was running the try catch without await the answer from AuthenticationServices.register so it was exiting the function before recieving an answer/error.

This is the correct version.

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      if (password === repeatPassword) {
        await AuthenticationServices.register({
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          password: password,
        });
        redirect();
        /*.then(redirect)
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            setUserData({
              ...userData,
              error: err.response.data.error,
            });
          });*/
      } else {
        setUserData({
          ...userData,
          error: "Passwords don't match",
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setUserData({
        ...userData,
        error: err.response.data.error,
      });
    }
  };
```